# Unable to scroll the grid until the end of the records

Tags: javascript, extjs, grid

I implemented a grid having behind a store with millions of records, for example 2.500.000.
The problem is that i am not able to scroll beyond the row 1597829.
If i change the theme from Gray to Triton, the last record is 1016800.

Below is my fiddle example:
https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2pnu

Comment: Millions of records is not much? If another approach is possible, it might be interesting to use **infinite scroll** ([fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/d9t&view/editor)) or **pagination** ([fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/pim&view/editor)).

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're running into is the natural element height limits of the browser. In 6.7.0, a virtual scroller was introduced, however it's not integrated into any of the components in classic, only modern. The reason why you see different results between themes is due to the row size. The smaller the rows, the more content you can fit before reaching the limit.

Comment: is there any possibility to pass beyond this limitation?

Comment: Not easily, no.